# Instructions/Recommendations for creating a Linux LiveCD/DVD?

Tags: linux, live-cd

It's been a few years since I've created a Linux [LiveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), so I thought I'd ask this community for some best practices before I make my next attempt.

My goal is to create a Linux Live CD/DVD for a reasonably new (less than 2 years old) PC (not Mac). When booted in Linux, the System will be used for "general" computing tasks like web browsing, word processing, and audio/video playback. This is neither a gaming machine, nor a development environment. The PC has a CD/DVD burner.

Specifically, I'm looking for reasonable choices for the following:

- **LiveCD/DVD distribution**. Preferably, something that has Firefox, OpenOffice, and a good collection of codecs "right out of the box."
- **CD/DVD burning software**. Ideally, I'd like some FOSS burner software that will let me do something like: put a blank CD/DVD into the drive, open the burner software, select the LiveCD/DVD ISO file, and hit the "go" button.

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu documentation has some howtos on how to create an Ubuntu Live CD. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Answer (score 1):

There even are tools that do this online. You select what should be placed on the CD/DVD, and the system makes an image for you to download: http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/02/create-custom-linux-distribution.html

Comment: Here's a direct link from the blog article: http://www.instalinux.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the openSUSE Build Service's KIWI program, which makes it easy to build your own openSUSE-based LiveCD/DVD. Currently, all the official install media for openSUSE is built using KIWI.

http://en.opensuse.org/LiveDVD

Answer (score 1):

You can check this out http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ you get so many thing to create Live CD as well your own server or desktop cd you create